# ts Property 'x' does not exist on type 'Reel'

Tags: typescript, pixi.js, tslint

I'm extending Container from PIXI.js:

```
export class Reel extends Container {
    constructor(width: number, height: number) {
        super();

        var sprite: Sprite = Sprite.fromImage("assets/images/elephant.png");
        super.addChild(sprite);
    }
}
```

But when I instantiate a new class and I try to access a Container property I got the tslint error: *[ts] Property 'x' does not exist on type 'Reel'*

```
var reel1: Reel = new Reel(100, 300);
reel1.x = 200;
```

Comment: are you not missing the namespace `PIXI.Container`?

Comment: I tried: import * as PIXI from "pixi.js"; export class Reel extends PIXI.Container {}

Comment: which version of typescript are you using?

Comment: I don't think it's related to the implementation, this simple example works: http://jsbin.com/muvepixize/edit?js,console

Comment: "typescript": "^2.5.3"

Answer (score 1):

Your import is wrong. You need to import the `Typescript Definitions for Pixi.js` from https://github.com/pixijs/pixi-typescript. Basically, you just need to do an

```
`npm install @types/pixi.js --save-dev`
```

from the directory you're working in. If you don't have a `node_modules` folder then one will be created for you. After that you just do

```
`import Container = PIXI.Container;`
```

and you're all set.

[image]

Comment: Since the error is with Typescript linter, you could try that code in [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/) or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) :) shorter and faster

Comment: At this point it’s not quicker. I’ve already written it here. This is Typescript. Angular isn’t making the property visible.

Comment: @TomSarduy - This is the correct answer. If you were the one who voted to delete my answer then perhaps this one works better for you. The problem wasn't going to be easy to solve on a web service and I don't use those anyway. That shouldn't be a reason to be penalized here.